# Json response with relationship in laravel blade

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

How can I get the **$levels** using ajax and display it inside a table..
Note: $levels has relationship..

**Controller:**

```
    public function days(Request $request){

    $levels=Level::with('lead')->get();

    $days=array();
    $id = $request->input('months');
    $month = $id;
    $year = 2018;
    for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++) 
    {
        $time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year);  
        if(date('m', $time)==$month && date('w', $time)>0 && date('w', $time)<6) 
        {
            $days[]=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
        } 
    }
    return response()->json($days);
   }
```

**Ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.testing').on('change',function(){
    var test=$(this).val(); 
    $.ajax({
     type:'get',
     url:'/days',
     data:{"months":test,"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
     success: function(data){
            $("#days").empty();
            $.each(data,function(index,value){
                $("#days").append('<input type="checkbox" checked 
           value="'+value+'" name="days[]"  > '+value+'<br/>');
            });
          }
      });
   }); 
});
```

................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: try this `return response()->json(['level' => $levels], 200);`

Comment: what will happen to my $days?

Comment: You can return whatever you want, I am telling you to use the same syntax.

Comment: the return is going inside the checkbox, how can i remove it from the checkbox?

Comment: try to console the data you are received using console.log(data). then post the result here.

Comment: i'm getting both DAYS and LEVELS no issue, but the only problem i have is LEVELS goes with the checkbox, is there a way that level will not go into the checkbox, i want it to go the table

Comment: post the result then maybe I can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should compact with an arrays like `return response()->json(['days' => $days, 'levels' => $levels]);`

**Controller**

```
public function days(Request $request){
    $levels=Level::with('lead')->get();

    $days=array();
    $id = $request->input('months');
    $month = $id;
    $year = 2018;
    for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++) {
        $time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year);  
        if(date('m', $time)==$month && date('w', $time)>0 && date('w', $time)<6) {
            $days[]=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
        } 
    }
    return response()->json(['days' => $days, 'levels' => $levels]);
}
```

**HTML sample**

```
<table class="table"></table>
```

**JS**
Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.testing').on('change',function(){
        var test=$(this).val(); 
        $.ajax({
         type:'get',
         url:'/days',
         data:{"months":test,"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
         success: function(data){
                $("#days").empty();
                $.each(data['days'],function(index,value){
                    $("#days").append('<input type="checkbox" checked value="'+value+'" name="days[]"  > '+value+'<br/>');
                });

                $.each(data['levels'],function(key,level){
                    $("table.table").append(
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<td>'+level.id+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+level.name+'</td>'+
                        '</tr>'
                    );
                   // added
                   // if you wish to put all together in one table its up you.
                   if(level.lead){
                        $.each(level.lead,function(leadKey,leadValue){
                            $("table2.table2").append(
                                '<tr>'+
                                    '<td>'+leadValue.id+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+leadValue.name+'</td>'+
                                '</tr>'
                            );
                        });
                    }
                     //
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: the lead is not coming out from the relationship

Comment: `level.lead.name`

Comment: post the data you are getting in response then it will easy for us to help you

Comment: i updated my answer, and do not copy paste, its just a sample.

Comment: the if statement is not working  i try to put the result on different table hehe

Comment: i just want to test if the lead is not empty,  try this `if(level.lead.length)`, it will count how many rows are in the lead object

Comment: its always telling me that level is not defined

Comment: actually there is an error in my answer i forgot to closed the closing parentheses in   `$.each(level.lead,function(leadKey,leadValue){`  with  `);`